# POSIX path with spaces in the filename

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to get the path of a single selected file (in Finder), but files with spaces in the filename don't work. I know I need to set quotes somewhere, but I just can't figure it out.

I would really appreciate a hint.

```
# Get selected files
set strFilePath to {}

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with objItem in (get selection)
        set end of strFilePath to POSIX path of (objItem as text)
        
    end repeat
end tell

# Use the path to synthesize a shell command and execute it.
do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine " & strFilePath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
set strFilePath to {}

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with objItem in (get selection)
        set end of strFilePath to POSIX path of (objItem as text)
    end repeat
end tell

# Use the path to synthesize a shell command and execute it.
repeat with i in strFilePath
    try
        do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine " & quoted form of i
    end try
end repeat
```